# Bigcartel, Neat theme, removing grid on the slider

Tags: themes, overlay, bigcartel

I know this has already been asked, but it was asked two years ago. I tried to add the code that was told to be put in at the end of my CSS.

This no longer works as of right now. Im desperate for any help right now. Everything is finished but this grid on my slideshow is bothering me...

GRID ISSUE:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just found this out.

Change the first two lines of **.flickity-viewport:after {** to

background-color: none;
background-image: url("{{ theme_image_url }}");

Comment: Life saver (sorry for late reply)